# How to fix issue with not being able to read checkbox values from angular form?

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to show a list of checkboxes and dynamically change that list on runtime. But once the new checkboxes are populated, the form.value has the updated list but not the updated values(based on user selection)

I have been following this article: https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-dynamic-checkbox-list-in-angular

This is my code to add the checkboxes:

```
private addCheckboxes() {
    const searchControls = (this.form.controls.searchDataControls as FormArray) ;
    while (searchControls.length !== 0) {
      searchControls.removeAt(0);
    }
    this.searchDataResult.map((o, i) => {
      const control = new FormControl();
      searchControls.push(control);
    });
  }
```

This is my code for submit:

```
  submitSelection() {
    const selectedData: number[] = this.form.value.searchDataControls
      .map((value: any, index: number) => (value ? this.searchDataResult[index].id : null))
      .filter((value: any) => value !== null);
  }
```

This works perfectly on first load. But when `addCheckboxes` is called a second time with new `searchDataResult`, `selectedData` is always empty.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz for this? I can help you there.

Comment: I make a simple stackblitz in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8q6p6b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html and work. See that you change the "searchDataResult" and call after to addCheckboxes(). See also that the searchDataResult must be an array ob objct with two properties: "id" and other (in the stackblitz "text" to show the options.